# RxSwift: Observe viewDidLoad from view model without Subjects

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

I have a dependency problem with my `UIViewController` and my view model.
Basically I want to listen the `viewDidLoad` event inside my view model.
At the moment I have a `Class A` which instantiates view model and `UIViewController` with parameter the viewModel, so:

```
let viewModel = ViewModel()
let viewController = UIViewController(viewModel)
```

and I've created a RxCocoa extension for the `viewDidLoad`:

```
var viewDidLoad: Observable<Void> {
    return self.sentMessage(#selector(Base.viewDidLoad)).map { _ in Void() }
}
```

now I'm stuck to bind this `rx.viewDidLoad` to an observable inside my view model. I am able to do it with `Subjects` but I want a reactive approach using just `Observable`.
I know that I could inject `rx.viewDidLoad` as constructor parameter of the view model but in this way I'd break my architecture and I don't want to allow the `UIViewController` to instantiate the view model internally but I want to keep it as a injected dependency.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

**Solution**

Thank to @tomahh I've used this solution:

My view controller:

```
override func configure(viewModel: ViewModel) {
    viewModel.bindViewDidLoad(rx.viewDidLoad)
}
```

My view model:

```
func bindViewDidLoad(_ viewControllerDidLoad: Observable<Void>) {
    //Create observers which depend on viewControllerDidLoad
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `ViewController` already knows about view model, it could set a property on `ViewModel` at initialisation time

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  init(_ viewModel: ViewModel) {
    viewModel.viewDidLoad = self.rx.viewDidLoad
  }
}
```

And then, observables in `ViewModel` could be defined as computed property deriving `viewDidLoad`

```
struct ViewModel {
  var viewDidLoad: Observable<Void> = .never()

  var something: Observable<String> {
     return viewDidLoad.map { "Huhu, something is guuut" }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm wondering if it's safe to allow the clients of the view model setting the `viewDidLoad` from outside. And if I use `something` before setting `viewDidLoad` then I wouldn't receive the events emitted by the `viewDidLoad`, would I ? Thank you for your answer btw

Comment: Actually I could solve these problems using a view model method like `setViewDidLoad(..)` where I set both `viewDidLoad` and `something` internally

Comment: You're making a valid point about using something before setting `viewDidLoad`. Maybe another way would be to use builder methods for something? Like `func something(using viewDidLoad: Observable<Void>) -> Observable<String>`?

Comment: I've used a view model method to bind the controller `viewDidLoad` and I could accept this new observable "lifecycle" as a good trade-off, I got rid of the Subject in this way. Thank you

Comment: But what do you think about the function approach? I actually like it better than what is suggested in the answer. I could update it if you agree.

Comment: I've edited my question adding my approach but feel free to update your answer. Depends if you prefer yours or "my" approach. Anyway I consider yours as accepted one since you gave me the right input for the solution. Up to you

Answer (score 2):

If anybody needs that rx properties here is a ready to use solution, inspired by the code of @marco-santarossa

```
extension Reactive where Base: UIView {
    var willMoveToWindow: Observable<Bool> {
        return self.sentMessage(#selector(Base.willMove(toWindow:)))
            .map({ $0.filter({ !($0 is NSNull) }) })
            .map({ $0.isEmpty == false })
    }
    var viewWillAppear: Observable<Void> {
        return self.willMoveToWindow
            .filter({ $0 })
            .map({ _ in Void() })
    }
    var viewWillDisappear: Observable<Void> {
        return self.willMoveToWindow
            .filter({ !$0 })
            .map({ _ in Void() })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let viewDidAppear = rx.sentMessage(#selector(UIViewController.viewDidAppear(_:)))
        .mapToVoid()
        .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: ())
```